# How to use .loc in fstrings?

Tags: python, string, pandas, indexing, f-string

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['abc', 'def', 'tre'],
                   'col2': ['foo', 'bar', 'stuff']})

  col1   col2
0  abc    foo
1  def    bar
2  tre  stuff
```

and a dictionary like this:

```
d = {'col1': [0, 2], 'col2': [1]}
```

The dictionary contains column names and indices of values to be extracted from the dataframe to generate strings like this:

```
abc (0, col1)
```

So, each string starts with the element itself and in parenthesis, the index and column name are shown.

I tried the following list comprehension:

```
l = [f"{df.loc[{indi}, {ci}]} ({indi}, {ci})"
     for ci, vali in d.items()
     for indi in vali]
```

which yields

```
['  col1\n0  abc (0, col1)',
 '  col1\n2  tre (2, col1)',
 '  col2\n1  bar (1, col2)']
```

So, it is almost ok, just the `col1\n0` parts need to be avoided.

If I try

```
f"{df.loc[0, 'col1']} is great"
```

I get

```
'abc is great'
```

as desired, however, with

```
x = 0
f"{df.loc[{x}, 'col1']} is great"
```

I get

```
'0    abc\nName: col1, dtype: object is great'
```

How could this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is the string representation, and ugly newline `\n` characters, of a `pd.Series` object returned by the `loc` acessor.

You should use [`pd.DataFrame.at`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html) to return scalars, and note there's no need here for nested `{}` for your index labels:

```
L = [f'{df.at[indi, ci]} ({indi}, {ci})' \
     for ci, vali in d.items() \
     for indi in vali]

print(L)

['abc (0, col1)', 'tre (2, col1)', 'bar (1, col2)']
```

Comment: Great, just removing the `{}` already solves it, even when `.loc` is used, but `.at` might be faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['abc', 'def', 'tre'],
                   'col2': ['foo', 'bar', 'stuff']})

d = {'col1': [0, 2], 'col2': [1]}
x = 0
[f"{df.loc[x, 'col1']} is great"
     for ci, vali in d.items()
     for indi in vali]
```

which gives you:

```
['abc is great', 'abc is great', 'abc is great']
```

is this what you're looking for?

#### Also you can do loop thru x range

```
[f"{df.loc[i, 'col1']} is great"
 for ci, vali in d.items()
 for indi in vali
 for i in range(2)]

#output
['abc is great',
 'def is great',
 'abc is great',
 'def is great',
 'abc is great',
 'def is great']
```

Comment: Thanks, but you do not use the dictionary `d`. But @jpp's answer solve sit. Was easier than expected.